# Remove element from jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery object that is created via jQuery `.find()` as seen below...

```
var $mytable= $('#mytable');
var $myObject = $mytable.find("tbody tr");
```

This works great and creates a jQuery object of all the `tr` elements in the `tbody`.  However, as I'm looping over the data, I need to be able to remove parts of the object as I go.  For instance, if the above call returns a jQuery object named `$myObject` with a length of 10, and I want to remove the index 10, I thought I could just do `$myObject.splice(10,1)` and it would remove the element at index 10.  However this doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas why?  Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I basically just want to be able to remove any element I want from $myObject as I loop through the data.  I know it's zero based (bad example above I guess), was just trying to get my point across.

**UPDATE**

Okay, so I create the object using the find method on the table and at it's creation it's length is 24.  As I loop over the object, when I hit an element I don't want I tried to use Array.prototype.splice.call($rows,x,1) where x represents the index to remove.  Afterwards when I view the object in the console, it still has a length of 24.

Comment: @A1rPun `$myObject.get().pop();`

Comment: @A.Wolff I soon realised :) But the answer depends on what the asker is doing with the output.

Comment: It's difficult to give you a "best" answer since you're not telling us what you're doing this for. What do you want to do with this jQuery object after you've selected it?

Comment: @Blazemonger I want to be able to remove elements from the object and have it re-indexed so if it has a length of 24, and I remove the data at index 15, it will show a new length of 23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`splice` is not part of the jQuery API, but you can apply native Array methods on jQuery collections by applying the prototype:

```
Array.prototype.splice.call($myObject, 9, 1); // 0-index
```

You can also use pop to remove the last item:

```
Array.prototype.pop.call($myObject);
```

This should also give you a correct `length` property.

Comment: sorry i read slice not splice but still splice() seems to work on jquery object

Comment: @A.Wolff splice method is correct.  Browser caching issues prevented me from seeing the results.  sorry for the trouble everyone.

Comment: @Phil You can use `.splice()` but be warned - it’s not an official part of the API and it might break at any release. See this line in the source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L124

Comment: @David if I use the prototype am I still vulnerable to potential breaks?

Comment: @Phil nope, it should be safe because you are basically using native array methods instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use `.not()` to remove a single element, then loop through the jQuery object at your leisure:

```
var $myObject = $mytable.find('tbody tr').not(':eq(9)'); // zero-based
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/tLP87/

http://api.jquery.com/not/

---

Or if you might be removing more than one:

```
var $myObject = $mytable.find("tbody tr:lt(9)");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/9evT8/

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: This is all about selectors, not modifying an existing collection.

Answer (score 1):

`splice` is an array method, not a jQuery object method.

Try [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Comment: This seems to work - define the jQuery collection object with: `var my_list_items = $("#my_list li")`, then, if required, delete the item at a particular index from the dom with `my_list_items.eq(9).remove()`, and then to remove the item from the jQuery collection object use `my_list_items.splice(9,1)`.  After the last action, `my_list_items.length` returns the original item count minus 1. Is there any reason this approach would be discouraged?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses zero-based arrays. This means that the final item in the array (i.e. the 10th item) will be at index 9.

```
$myObject[9]
```

So you need something like this:

```
$myObject.splice(9, 1);
```

This will remove the element from your existing array, and also return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .remove to remove an element from the DOM.

So to remove the element at index 9 of the `$myObject` array, use:

```
$myObject.eq(9).remove();
```

If you want to keep the element that you are removing, you can also do:

```
var removedElement = $myObject.eq(9);
removedElement.detach();
```

Comment: Why the downvote? He said he wanted to remove the element. He didn't say he just wanted it removed from the array. This does exactly that.

Comment: I didnt downvoted, but it is probly because `.remove()` is a jQuery function. By using `[10]`, you are losing the jQuery object. It become a DOM element. Also, it is 0 based index, so it should be 9, not 10.

Comment: Also I know it is a 0 based index, I never said it wasn't notice I said remove the 'element at index 10' not 'the 10th element'. But if that is a big problem I can change it to 9 instead.

Comment: Not related, but just to inform you that your second statement *"If you want to keep the element that you are removing, you can also do"* is false. `.remove()` will destroy the element. I think you meant `detach()`.

Comment: I downvoted because `get()` or `[]` returns a native dom node (or an array of dom nodes) and you can’t apply jquery methods on them (although there is an experimental `remove()` method on native nodes, but it’s not really standardized yet).

Comment: Sorry you are correct about the `.detach()` instead of `.remove()` thing. I knew that something would remove it without distroying the object.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use filter :

```
var $myObject = $mytable.find("tbody tr").filter(':lt(9)');
```